# How would I extract features from a text file and then use this to extract the information i need from the same file?

Tags: python, extract

So the file I'm working with is a gene annotation and it looks like this. There is a big block of text at the bottom that represents the whole genome sequence of the organism (often very large).[image]

I need to extract the genes that have tRNA next to them, as I've highlighted in the image. There are many of these in one file and I need to do this for over 150 to get a list of tRNA feature genes. My issue is that I was previously using a table that had the start and stop positions of each gene, but they were all protein coding. I now need non protein coding tRNA genes and these aren't listed anywhere.

How would I extract the start and stop positions for each tRNA gene and then use this to extract it from the sequence?

I have a skeleton script that extracts the genome chunk and I know I have to use this once I put my start and stop positions in a list, but this first part I'm stumped.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: What format is the table? what are you using to read it? pandas?

Comment: @Ivan I can't use the table because it doesnt contain the info I need. Instead, I need to go through the text file and extract the sequences linked to the tRNA tag if that makes sense?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. There's text on the image, maybe I could be usefull to share it as text instead of image. I have 2 advices. 1. use Regular expresions to find where "tRNA" and get it's value until the next change of line or 2. Use pandas' library to read and format the complete file. I expect updates to help u farther into the problem :)

Comment: Thank you @Ivan! I've managed to extract the information I need (I tried with regex but was too complicated for my knowledge level) but it isnt writing to my file :( Please see my latest question